# Python Segmentation Fault 11 with ThreadPoolExecutor and requests

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, threadpoolexecutor

I encounter randomly this error `Segmentation Fault 11` and don't really know how to manage it :

```
import concurrent.futures
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import requests

def run() :
    url = "https://www.stackoverflow.com/"
    items = [url +"?id="+str(i) for i in range(1000)]
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
        future_to_groups = {executor.submit(fetch, item): item for item in items}
    
        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_groups):
            data = future_to_groups[future]
            try:
                # Receive the returned result of current user
                print(data)
            except Exception as exc:
                print('%r generated an exception: %s' % (data, exc))

def fetch(url) :
    data = requests.get(url)
    return data

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

any idea how to tackle this ?

I get an update :
while happening, I get another error related to memory : `interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT`

the pop up that opens says :

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x7fa863bb49f0: pointer being freed was not allocated
```

Comment: Please fix the formatting. Your indentation is ambiguous and could be what's causing your issue

Comment: done, sorry for that. the bug is not about the indentation, I did a bad copy/paste here

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? I tried running your code on 3.8.0 without problems. Also, at which point of the execution do you get the segfault? Does anything get printed beforehand?

Comment: Side note to anyone wanting to test this code: running it is going to get your IP rate-limited on Stack Overflow...

Comment: @seb as I said, it's not showing up all the time. nothing else printed, the script stops and print "segmentation default 11". I have this error on python 3.7.3 on mac os, and python 3.7.8 on ubuntu 16.04

Comment: you can change the domain name to something else